# Form in class library not top most C#

Tags: c#

I currently have a form that loads information into it via class library, but am having difficulty with it showing as top most. It goes behind the window running the class library API. Any tips? How do I force the form to be topmost?

Comment: "ignore most of it unless..." - that's usually a good indication that you should put more effort into creating a [mcve]. *Reducing* your code down to the minimal example that demonstrates the problem is, among other things, a *valuable* debugging skill in and of itself.

Comment: I wasn't sure if the background of the code was needed to know how the Variables were retrieved and what the API type is. I'm still pretty new to this so I basically just put it all in there and tried to explain. Sorry I'm not used to the customs of the debugging environment here :/ I'll work to be better at this!

Comment: There is a property named `TopMost` for all of the forms in C#, set its value to `true`.

Comment: Thanks @Nofuzy. I modified the question and the answer to better reflect my issue and solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If my comment was right, then I submit it as answer:

There is a property named `TopMost` for all of the forms in C#, set its value to `true`.

Answer (score 0):

@nofuzzy was correct. When I set the TopMost property to true, it worked. Thanks!

when the form loads, I have:

```
_form1.TopMost = true;
```